# React > Define a common useEffect to use across components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

Innocent React question here.

I have a `useEffect` method that closes a modal on the `escape` keypress, that is duplicated a few times in my code, that looks like this:

```
const [shouldShowModal, setShouldShowModal] = useProfileModal();

useEffect(() => {
  const closeModalOnEscape = (e: KeyboardEvent | any): void => {
    if (e.key === "Escape") setShouldShowModal(false);
  };
  document.addEventListener("keydown", closeModalOnEscape);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", closeModalOnEscape);
  };
}, [setShouldShowModal]);
```

Is there a way I can define the `useEffect` piece to use across multiple components?

Comment: Does every use of `useProfileModal` also use this effect hook?

Comment: Yes @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a custom hook that takes in a setter

```
const useCloseModalOnEscape = (setShouldShowModal) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const closeModalOnEscape = (e: KeyboardEvent | any): void => {
      if (e.key === "Escape") setShouldShowModal(false);
    };
    document.addEventListener("keydown", closeModalOnEscape);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", closeModalOnEscape);
    };
  }, [setShouldShowModal]);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
const [shouldShowModal, setShouldShowModal] = useProfileModal();

useCloseModalOnEscape(setShouldShowModal);
```

You can rename `setShouldShowModal` or `useCloseModalOnEscape` to be something more accurate to your other use cases if they're not all in the context of closing modals.

---

If every instance of `useProfileModal` will close on escape, then you should just include the `useEffect` (from inside of `useCloseModalOnEscape`) in `useProfileModal`.

Answer (score 1):

Since every use of `useProfileModal` uses the effect, just put the effect inside `useProfileModal`. That way, the code in every component only needs to be

```
const [shouldShowModal, setShouldShowModal] = useProfileModal();
```

and have, in `useProfileModal`:

```
const useProfileModal = () => {
  // ...
  useEffect(() => {
    const closeModalOnEscape = (e: KeyboardEvent | any): void => {
      if (e.key === "Escape") setShouldShowModal(false);
    };
    document.addEventListener("keydown", closeModalOnEscape);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", closeModalOnEscape);
    };
  }, [setShouldShowModal]);
  // ...
  return [shouldShowModal, setShouldShowModal];
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. Wish I could give two answers for this question (one for you and to Samathingamajig)